# How to use grpc-web with the code first grpc services using protobuf-net?

Tags: grpc, protobuf-net, grpc-web

We have developed grpc services using codefirst protobuf-net method. How can we call these services from javascript using grpc-web? how do we generate grpc javascript client code if we dont have .proto files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/createProtoFile to convert to your codefirst files to protobuf files. Something like this, using the `protobuf-net.Reflection` package:

```
var generator = new SchemaGenerator
{
    ProtoSyntax = ProtoSyntax.Proto3
};

var schema = generator.GetSchema<ICalculator>(); // there is also a non-generic overload that takes Type

using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("services.proto"))
{
    await writer.WriteAsync(schema);
}
```